# Streaming video in a folder with ffmpeg

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, rtmp

I have configured RTMP to work with Nginx on ubuntu server following the guide from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Js1OlvRNsdI
I have tested the setup and everything is working perfectly to the end but then I have a folder containing movies and I want them to be streamed or played independently via a web player, for example, JWPlayer and I have failed to get that implementation online. Is there anyone with an idea of how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a folder contains a set of movies, and you want to stream them as a stream, or each file as a stream?

Whatever you could do this by FFmpeg:

```sh
for file in $(ls movies/*.mp4); do 
  ffmpeg -re -i $file -c copy -f flv rtmp://server/app/stream
done
```

If want to stream each file as a stream, try to start multiple ffmpeg to do this.